# Mobius transform |z|<1 to the right half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

> Find a Mobius transformation mapping the unit disk {|z| < 1} into the right half-plane and taking z = −i to the origin.

My workings:
$\phi(t) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$

We map -i to the origin (0) by taking the numerator and equating it to 0, knowing b = +i (since we started at -i).

That is: 
$az+i=0 \implies i = b, a = 1$, which is correct.

However, how do we map $|z|$ to the upper right half plane (i.e. Re(w) = 0)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch that first step:  $-ai+b=0\implies b=ai$.  Let's have $-1\to i$, so that $-a+ai=i(-c+d)$. And $0\to1$, giving $b=d$.  So $c=-a$.

So, we get $f(z)=\frac{az+ai}{-az+ai}$ or $\boxed{f(z)=\frac{z+i}{i-z}}$.

By specifying the values at $3$ points,  the Möbius transformation is determined.

Comment: Correct answer. Can you elaborate on why you said "let's have -1 -> i? And how did you choose -1?

Comment: $-1$ is another point on $\mid z\mid=1$ (besides $-i$), and I wish to move it onto the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

It is $\frac {1-iz} {1+iz}$. Multiply numerator and denominator by $1-i\overline {z}$ to prove that this works.

Comment: You said upper half plane in the title and right half plane in the question. I have taken it as right half plane.

Comment: Yes, thanks for spotting that. I've edited the question title. In regards to your answer, how do you get that value?

Comment: You can start with $1-iz$ in the numerator so that it vanishes at $-i$. Take denominator as $a+bz$,  multiply numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator. You then want the  real part of the numerator to be positive when $|z| <1$. It should be easy to  guess what $a$ and $b$ should be.